# How can I draw a vertical line on a slide in beamer without affecting the positions of any other elements on the page?

Tags: beamer, rules

Consider the following beamer frame

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Foo Bar}
\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{figures/Fig1.pdf}
\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{figures/Fig2.pdf}
\end{frame}
```

Currently, they are laid out **exactly as I want them**, with Fig1 on the left, and Fig2 on the right.

I want to add a vertical line right in between them, *without modifying the positions of the figures at all*.

I tried adding the following in between the two `includegraphics` lines, but it blew away the positions of both figures.

```
\rule{1 pt}{300 pt}
```

What is the simplest way to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `\vrule`.

Here's an example with fake images, replace them with yours.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Foo Bar}
\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{example-image-a}
\hspace{5pt}\vrule\hspace{5pt}%
\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{example-image-b}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

If you want to change the thickness of the rule, use something like

```
\vrule width 1pt
```

instead of simply `\vrule`.

[image]